# Job waiting on CXCONSUMER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, wait-types

We have got a procedure on SQL Server agent jobs and this job started to hang on transaction for many hours with wait stats CXCONSUMER and never complete. The problem is after we noticed that it was hanging we kill the job and started manually during and the job was working fine and completing. But right now neither starting manually or on sql agent job seems never completing and hanging on waits with CXCONSUMER.

According to sp_who2, sp_whoisactive and sql server profiler there are no active locks it is waiting for. It keeps yielding CXCONSUMER and it's processor time and does basically nothing.  Here is the execution plan after 3h -

And the other symptoms is the tempdb is unaccesible through properties when this job runs I get this error "Property SpaceAvailable is not available for Database '[tempdb]'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights" despite there are available space on tempdb.

I will appreciate your help in this matter.

Thank you and Best Regards,[image]

Comment: Is that the actual plan? I can't see any actual values on any of the operators. It looks like the optimizer is trying to push 65m rows from the index seek on MSEG into a nested loops operator (designed for small datasets) what happens if you update statisitcs on the MSEG table as it seems there has been a large number of updates since the stats were updated on that table...also, do you get poor performance when just running the `SELECT...FROM..#repositioning` query on its own?

Comment: Despite the lack of reply to my comment, I've added a bounty on this question as I see this problem a lot (an inappropriate number of rows being pushed through a nested loop) and am interested in what could cause it. The MSEG table in the which the clustered index seek is being performed on appears to have had around 300k changes since the last stats update so perhaps a stats update is required (Although I suspect this won't help) Is a more covering index on MSEG table which includes the residual predicates required? Or a way to re-write the query which tocause a better operator choice?

Comment: I've just noticed there are mismatched column types in the join between NGOCustomizing and MSEG has mismatched data types - try changing the type of the NGOCustomizing to NVARCHAR (or try an explicit CONVERT in the join)

Answer (score 14):

There are really two questions in this question:

1. Why is the query slow?
2. Why are tempdb properties inaccessible?

Let's start with #2.

### Why are tempdb properties inaccessible?

You get this error:

> Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt) Property SpaceAvailable is not
> available for Database '[tempdb]'. This property may not exist for
> this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access
> rights. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

[image: SSMS Error dialog]

This will happen when you create a temp table inside a transaction. The `CREATE TABLE` holds metadata locks on system tables that blocks the queries to populate the database properties window, and causes the opening of that dialog to time out & show this error.

If you run this statement in SSMS, and try to open the tempdb properties window at the same time, I expect it will open just fine:

```
SELECT o1.object_id
INTO #blep
FROM sys.objects o1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o4
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o5;
```

However, with the same query dropped into a transaction, and you will get the above error that you reported getting:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT o1.object_id
INTO #blep
FROM sys.objects o1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o4
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o5;
```

While you didn't provide the code beyond what is included in the plan, the behavior would indicate that your `SELECT...INTO` is happening within a transaction, similar to the above example.

I would recommend *never* creating a temp table within a transaction, due to the blocking on system tables within tempdb. This affects concurrency, in addition to operational issues like the one with the database properties window.

If your procedure requires the use of transactions, you should create the table OUTSIDE the transaction, then begin the transaction & do the necessary work. If you depend on the behavior of `SELECT...INTO` to define the schema (ex, with a dynamic/unknown schema), use `SELECT...INTO...WHERE 1=2;` to create the table empty, then proceed after that to begin your transaction and do work.

Now, on to the other question:

### Why is the query slow?

I'm not sure which line in the `sp_whoisactive` output correlates to your query. All of them? Session_id 797 is showing high `CXCONSUMER` waits, and has been running for 2 hours. I'll assume that is the problematic session. It has performed almost 57.9 million milliseconds of CPU cycles (967 minutes) in 2h 12mi of "real" time (132 minutes). That's about 7x more CPU time than "real" time--which certainly indicates that it is busy doing parallel work.

I can tell from the schema that this is an SAP database. The SAP schema is a bit of a quirky one, with the `MANDT` column being the leading column on every clustered composite index. This column is basically "company code" and used to separate data for various subsidiaries. SAP supplies this column within the join/filter predicate on EVERY query to ensure it's working with data for the right company. If your company doesn't keep separate books for separate subsidiaries, then the `MANDT` column is always the exact same value.

Because the non-selective predicate is supplied, it can trick SQL Server into showing a *seek* on the clustered primary key, when it's really doing a table *scan*. If every row has a value of `AMTWO` for `MANDT`, and you query `AND MANDT = 'AMTWO'`, the optimizer *might* think "Hey, that's the leading column on the PK, I can seek to that!" But in reality, it seeks to the first occurrence of that value (ie the first row) and reads through to the last occurrence of that value (ie, the last row). Because every row is exactly the same value, so it has to *scan* every row, even though it shows as a seek in the plan.

The reality is that there's a better index to use, but SQL Server didn't realize that another index (or combination of indexes) would perform better.

Additionally, depending on your SQL Server version and whether you are using [Trace Flag 2389](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-statistics/trace-flag-2389-new-cardinality-estimator), SAP often struggles with the "Ascending key problem" related to their heavy use of dates to key transactional data.

Both of these problems can be resolved by aggressively [updating statistics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/managing-sql-server-statistics/) on your SAP database.

There certainly could be something more going on with your query more than stats, but based on my experience with SAP, ensuring you have up-to-date stats would be at the top of my priority list.

You say it "started to hang on transaction for many hours"... how fast was it running before? Was it processing a similar amount of data was fast? The plan indicates it's working off just over a million rows in `#repositioning`, 200k rows in `#stock` and 65 million rows in `MSEG`---so I wouldn't expect the query to be extremely fast to begin with.

After you update stats, I'd be keen to capture **actual** IO & CPU costs for an execution of this code, using something like [Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer), as that often gives much more insight into the problem, particularly if it's a case where SQL Server has selected a "bad" plan, and a better/faster plan exists but wasn't chosen.

Comment: It sounds like the MANDT column can have duplicate values - "This column is basically "company code" and used to separate data for various subsidiaries." but yet you say it's the primary key - "it can trick SQL Server into showing a seek on the clustered primary key". Am I misunderstanding something? Apoligies, I'm unfamiliar with the SAP schema

Comment: Let's say you have 1000000 transactions in your SAP database. If you have only one "company" then all 1000000 transactions will have the same value for MANDT. MANDT is the first column in the composite clustered primary key, along with some other columns that will uniquely identify the transaction

Comment: ah, the clustered *composite* primary key. That makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: As the OP unfortunately doesn't appear to be coming back with answers to any of our questions, I'll award this bounty